# Using _find from the command line

Tags: couchdb

My CouchDB (version 1.7.1_5) setup:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/shop
$ curl -d "{\"type\": \"product\", \"name\": \"Apple\", \"price\": \"1\"}" \
  -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:5984/shop/ 
{"ok":true,"id":"1ce330a867a803fd10082c451304075b",
"rev":"1-f61d5b64af58a6eda60ac0c9160ad690"}
```

Now I want to find the product with the name `Apple`. According to http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html I should use `_find` for this. But I can't find the right syntax. What's wrong with this request?

```
$ curl -d "{\"selector\": {\"name\": \"Apple\"}}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5984/shop/_find
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mango query server, one behind an end-point `/{db}/_find`, only included in CouchDB starting from [version 2.0.0](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/whatsnew/2.0.html#version-2-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your CouchDB version. What is it? The mango queries like `_find` API are not supported in CouchDB 1.6.1.

Comment: I added the version number in the question (1.7.1_5).